# XML Parsing: How to ignore hard-coded '<' inside string?

Tags: android, html, xml, xmlpullparser

I am using XMLPullParser on Android to read the XML of this site: https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/abaddon/matchups?date=patch_7.07b

What I want to read is just some info on the huge line 14.

At some point before that line, there is a `'<'` inside a string so I get this error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Illegal: "<" inside attribute value 

(position:START_TAG <iframe id='vmv2-frm-'+id+'' src='kunkka-unit kunkka-leaderboard'>@3:5973 in java.io.InputStreamReader@7f90d80)
```

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185005/xml-illegal-attribute-value) question but since the page is not mine, there is nothing I can do to change the `'<'`.

I have no idea how to fix this, maybe there is a way to completely ignore the above lines that cause the error?

Comment: basically, you have to make the `String` a valid XML. Invalid XML should not be parsed in any case. So you have to somehow find and fix your `>`

Comment: The XML code is not mine, I just read it.

Comment: It does not matter. It is not valid XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code ,

```
YourString.replaceAll("<","")
```

it will replace the "<" value in your string with an empty string.

Comment: What do you mean by 'YourString'? All I have is an InputStream that contains all the XML inside it.